# Creating Hadoop Cluster in ubuntu using laptop and desktop

Tags: 13.10, hadoop

I am learning *Hadoop*. I want to install *Hadoop* in such a way that my laptop and desktop are in a cluster.

I do have connectivity between them using SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Hadoop on any of the machine don't have to think whether it is laptop or desktop you have to make sure for the connectivity between them. And perform all the necessary steps to install Hadoop if you want any document to install Hadoop (apache hadoop) please comment I can provide you one.

And it is not clear with your question what you want exactly....

If you want something else please clarify